# Convergence, continuity and a continuous derivative $\ \sum_{n\geq 1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{x^2+n^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to determine whether this power series (or function):

$$\ f(x)=\sum_{1\leq n}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{x^2+n^4}~~~~x>0$$

is convergent, whether this function is continuous and whether it has a continuous derivative at every point of its interval and the last part seems to be a little tricky for me.

**My steps**
The uniform convergence of the power series:
$$ \sup_{x\in(0,\infty)} \frac{nx}{x^2+n^4} = \frac{1}{2n} \\ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{nx}{x^2+n^4} = 0$$
It isnt' convergent uniformly.

Almost uniform convergence:
$$ a\in(0, \infty), ~~x\in(a, 5a) \\ \sup_{x\in(a, 5a)} \frac{nx}{x^2+n^4} \geq \frac{5a}{25a^2+n^4}  $$
It isnt' convergent almost uniformly.

Pointwise convergence:
$$ \frac{nx}{x^2+n^4} \leq \frac{nx}{n^4} = \frac{x}{n^3}$$
It is pointwise convergent from comparison to $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ and asymptotic similarity.

Since the series is convergent, it represents a **continuous** function within its radius of convergence.

Question:

**What about the derivative at the every point?** A differentiable ower series has to be convergent and to have almost uniform or uniform convergetn series of derivatives. Then I should check whether these derivatives are continuous. However, I am stuck at this point:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{n^5-nx^2}{(x^2+n^4)^2}=0 \\ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{n^5-nx^2}{(x^2+n^4)^2}=0\\ $$

$$(\frac{nx}{x^2+n^4})'= \frac{n^5-nx^2}{(x^2+n^4)^2} \\ x=n^2\\ \sup_{x\in(0,\infty)} \frac{nx}{x^2+n^4} = \frac{1}{2n}\\ $$

It indicates that the power series is not differentiable, from the divergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n}$, therefore it cannot have a continuous derivative. **Does that make sense**? Or am I wrong in the particuar equation? I would appreciate your hints.

Edits to the post made with Bernard's help.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! $\sup_{x>0}\dfrac{nx}{x^2+n^4}=\dfrac 1{2n}$ if my calculations are correct.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your welcoming. How did you find $\frac{1}{2n}$? Additionally, any other suggestions?

Comment: I simply computed the derivatives to determine the variations of the function and obtained a maximum for $\:x=n^2$.

Comment: Nice, but have you compared the derivative to zero? That's the point that intrigues me, because I can imagine nx=0 in that case

Comment: The derivative is $\dfrac{n(n^4-x^2)}{(x^2+n^4)^2}$ so it has the sign of $n^2-x$ on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I was thinking about the antiderivative. Anyway, does the rest seem to be correct?

Comment: No. The limit of the derivative at $\infty$ is $0$ (consider the ratio of the leading terms), and at $0$, just substitute $x$ with $0$.

Comment: Fixed! Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

**You make an error in proving continuity:**

This is not a power series in the conventional sense; that is, it is not a sum of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}$.  Thus pointwise convergence does *not* suffice to show that the resulting sum is continuous. (In fact, this is always true; the corresponding result for power series uses that fact that pointwise convergence of a power series implies uniform convergence.)

It *can* be written as a power series using complex-analytic methods, but your tags suggest you are not familiar with those techniques.

**The key to this problem is analyzing the behavior of each term.**

For fixed $n$, let $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{x^2+n^4}$.  Maximizing $f_n$ was a good first step, and you correctly found the maximum to be $\frac{1}{2n}$.  But you ignored the key issue of *where* the maximum appears.   $f_n$ is maximized at $x=n^2$.

This is the infamous "moving hump": the maximum is relatively large, but increasing $n$ pushes it further and further from the origin.  To be more precise: on any fixed interval $[0,K]$, only finitely many $n$ have $n^2\in[0,K]$, so only finitely many terms of the sum "see" the full maximum.  All others end up "pegged" at $K$, so that their maximum is $\frac{nK}{K^2+n^4}=o(n^{-3})$.

Thus on any $[0,K]$, the convergence is uniform.  This proves continuity.

**For the derivative, you should demonstrate convergence in the $C^1$ norm.**

We've already shown uniform convergence, so all that remains is to show uniform convergence of $\sum_n{f_n'}$.  I leave it to you to provide the details.

(*Hint: Weierstrass $M$-test*)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very clear and detailed. You have noticed a very simple and obvious mistake in the beginning. However, I would like to ask you whether I use Weierstrass M-test properly: $\frac{n^5-nx^2}{(x^2+n^4)^2}<\frac{n^5-nx^2}{n^8}<\frac{n^5}{n^8}=\frac{1}{n^3}$ which converges and from Weierstrass we have uniform convergency, thus series of derivatives is a continuous function. Is it correct?

Comment: @Funny: Yes, that is the proof I had in mind.